# Slow async bulk import via RabbitMQ, no multiple threads?

Tags: magento2.3, import, rabbit-mq, bulk, async

I really hope someone can help me out here. We have setup a RabbitMQ and a Magento 2.3.4. RabbitMQ runs and get about 83k messages via an import by our external product management software. There are about 19k products, 4 different storeviews and simple as well as grouped products. Every product has at least 2 images.

The way we do it now is, that we upload roughly 12 GiB of images in a folder. We use a plugin for Magento (https://github.com/olivertar/m2_api_product_images/) which is modified a bit regarding 2.3.4. It works and imports all the products, BUT the import takes about 20 hrs.

[image]

This is what's happening while importing. In the background you can see the graphs from RabbitMQ. The last argument which is not visible on the screenshot is the max-messages which is set to 10.000.

What I don't get here is, why is only one single CPU is used? If all 8 cores, or at least 6 would be used at the same time, it would be enough already. CPU usage on that single task is high, but memory very low. On which ends do I have to change the configuration to get to that? All those imports go to the REST API via async call (.../async/bulk/V1/products...).

My env.php configuration regarding AMQP is this:

```
'queue' => [
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '...',
        'user' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'virtualhost' => '/'
    ],
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
],
```

Any ideas?